# Rust - adding event listeners to a webassembly game

Tags: events, rust, webassembly, game-loop

I'm attempting to create a game in web assembly. I chose to prepare it in rust and compile it using cargo-web. I managed to get a working game loop, but I have a problem with adding MouseDownEvent listener due to rust borrowing mechanisms. I would very much prefer to write "safe" code (without using "unsafe" keyword)

At this moment the game simply moves a red box from (0,0) to (700,500) with speed depending on the distance. I would like to have the next step to use user click update the destination.

This is the simplified and working code of the game.

static/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>The Game!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600">
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

src/main.rs

```
mod game;

use game::Game;

use stdweb::console;
use stdweb::traits::*;
use stdweb::unstable::TryInto;
use stdweb::web::document;
use stdweb::web::CanvasRenderingContext2d;
use stdweb::web::html_element::CanvasElement;

use stdweb::web::event::MouseDownEvent;

fn main()
{
    let canvas: CanvasElement = document()
        .query_selector("#canvas")
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap()
        .try_into()
        .unwrap();

    canvas.set_width(800u32);
    canvas.set_height(600u32);


    let context = canvas.get_context().unwrap();

    let game: Game = Game::new();

    // canvas.add_event_listener(|event: MouseDownEvent|
    // {
    //     game.destination.x = (event.client_x() as f64);
    //     game.destination.y = (event.client_y() as f64);
    // });

    game_loop(game, context, 0f64);
}


fn game_loop(mut game : Game, context : CanvasRenderingContext2d, timestamp : f64)
{
    game.cycle(timestamp);
    draw(&game,&context);

    stdweb::web::window().request_animation_frame( |time : f64| { game_loop(game, context, time); } );
}


fn draw(game : &Game, context: &CanvasRenderingContext2d)
{
    context.clear_rect(0f64,0f64,800f64,800f64);
    context.set_fill_style_color("red");
    context.fill_rect(game.location.x, game.location.y, 5f64, 5f64);
}
```

src/game.rs

```
pub struct Point
{
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
}

pub struct Game
{
    pub time: f64,
    pub location: Point,
    pub destination: Point,
}

impl Game
{
    pub fn new() -> Game
    {
        let game = Game
        {   
            time: 0f64,
            location: Point{x: 0f64, y: 0f64},
            destination: Point{x: 700f64, y: 500f64},
        };

        return game;
    }

    pub fn cycle(&mut self, timestamp : f64)
    {
        if timestamp - self.time > 10f64
        {
            self.location.x += (self.destination.x - self.location.x) / 10f64; 
            self.location.y += (self.destination.y - self.location.y) / 10f64;

            self.time = timestamp;
        }
    }
}
```

The commented out part of main.rs is my attempt of adding a MouseDownEvent listener. Unfortunately it generates a compilation error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `game` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:37:15
   |
31 |       canvas.add_event_listener(|event: MouseDownEvent|
   |       -                         ----------------------- borrow of `game` occurs here
   |  _____|
   | |
32 | |     {
33 | |         game.destination.x = (event.client_x() as f64);
   | |         ---- borrow occurs due to use in closure
34 | |         game.destination.y = (event.client_y() as f64);
35 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `game` is borrowed for `'static`
36 |
37 |       game_loop(game, context, 0f64);
   |                 ^^^^ move out of `game` occurs here
```

I would very much like to know how to properly implement a way of reading user input into a game. It doesn't need to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `game_loop` owns `game`, as it is moved into the loop. So anything that should change game needs to happen inside `game_loop`. To fit event handling into this, you have multiple options:

#### Option 1

**Let the `game_loop` poll for events.**

You create a queue of events and your `game_loop` will have some logic to get the first event and handle it.

You will have to deal with synchronization here, so I suggest that you read up on [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) and [Concurrency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/book/concurrency.html) in general. But it should be a fairly easy task once you get the hang of it. Your loop gets one reference and each event handler gets one, all try to unlock the mutex and then access the queue (vector probably).

This will make your `game_loop` the monolithic one truth of them all, which is a popular engine design because it is easy to reason about and start with.

But maybe you want to be less centralized.

### Option 2

**Let events happen outside the loop**

This idea would be a bigger refactor. You would put your `Game` in a [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.3.0/lazy_static/) with a Mutex around it.

Every invocation of the `game_loop` it will try to get the lock on said Mutex and then perform game calculations.

When an input event happens, that event also tries to get the Mutex on the `Game`. This means while the `game_loop` is processing, no input events are handled, but they will try to get in between ticks.

A challenge here would be to preserve input order and to make sure that inputs are processed quick enough. This might be a bigger challenge to get completely right. But the design will give you some possibilities.

A fleshed out version of this idea is [`Amethyst`](https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst), which is massively parallel and makes for a clean design. But they employ a quite more complex design behind their engine.

Comment: Actually lazy_static with Mutex were not a large code refactor. This way I achieved a singleton pattern which to me is the correct way of implementing this logic.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the compiler error message is pretty clear in this case. You're trying to borrow the `game` in the closure for the `'static` lifetime and then you're also trying to move the `game`. It isn't allowed. I'd recommend to read [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) book again. Focus on chapter 4 - Understanding Ownership.

To make it shorter, your question boils down to something like - *how to share a state, which can be mutated*. There're plenty of ways how to achieve this goal, but it really depends on your needs (single or multi thread, etc.). I'm going to use `Rc` & `RefCell` for this problem.

`Rc` ([std::rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html)):

> The type `Rc<T>` provides shared ownership of a value of type `T`, allocated in the heap. Invoking `clone` on `Rc` produces a new pointer to the same value in the heap. When the last `Rc` pointer to a given value is destroyed, the pointed-to value is also destroyed.

`RefCell` ([std::cell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/index.html)):

> Values of the `Cell<T>` and `RefCell<T>` types may be mutated through shared references (i.e. the common `&T` type), whereas most Rust types can only be mutated through unique (`&mut T`) references. We say that `Cell<T>` and `RefCell<T>` provide 'interior mutability', in contrast with typical Rust types that exhibit 'inherited mutability'.

Here's what I did to your structures:

```rust
struct Inner {
    time: f64,
    location: Point,
    destination: Point,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Game {
    inner: Rc<RefCell<Inner>>,
}
```

What does this mean? `Inner` holds the game state (same fields as the old `Game`). New `Game` has just one field `inner`, which contains the shared state.

- `Rc<T>` (`T` is `RefCell<Inner`> in this case) - allows me to clone `inner` multiple times, but it won't clone the `T`
- `RefCell<T>` (`T` is `Inner` in this case) - allows me to borrow `T` immutably or mutably, checking is done in the runtime

I can clone the `Game` structure multiple times now and it won't clone the `RefCell<Inner>`, just the `Game` & `Rc`. Which is what the `enclose!` macro is doing in the updated `main.rs`:

```rust
let game: Game = Game::default();

canvas.add_event_listener(enclose!( (game) move |event: MouseDownEvent| {
    game.set_destination(event);
}));

game_loop(game, context, 0.);
```

Without the `enclose!` macro:

```rust
let game: Game = Game::default();

// game_for_mouse_down_event_closure holds the reference to the
// same `RefCell<Inner>` as the initial `game`
let game_for_mouse_down_event_closure = game.clone();
canvas.add_event_listener(move |event: MouseDownEvent| {
    game_for_mouse_down_event_closure.set_destination(event);
});

game_loop(game, context, 0.);
```

---

Updated `game.rs`:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

use stdweb::traits::IMouseEvent;
use stdweb::web::event::MouseDownEvent;

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
}

impl From<MouseDownEvent> for Point {
    fn from(e: MouseDownEvent) -> Self {
        Self {
            x: e.client_x() as f64,
            y: e.client_y() as f64,
        }
    }
}

struct Inner {
    time: f64,
    location: Point,
    destination: Point,
}

impl Default for Inner {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Inner {
            time: 0.,
            location: Point { x: 0., y: 0. },
            destination: Point { x: 700., y: 500. },
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Game {
    inner: Rc<RefCell<Inner>>,
}

impl Default for Game {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Game {
            inner: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Inner::default())),
        }
    }
}

impl Game {
    pub fn update(&self, timestamp: f64) {
        let mut inner = self.inner.borrow_mut();

        if timestamp - inner.time > 10f64 {
            inner.location.x += (inner.destination.x - inner.location.x) / 10f64;
            inner.location.y += (inner.destination.y - inner.location.y) / 10f64;

            inner.time = timestamp;
        }
    }

    pub fn set_destination<T: Into<Point>>(&self, location: T) {
        let mut inner = self.inner.borrow_mut();
        inner.destination = location.into();
    }

    pub fn location(&self) -> Point {
        self.inner.borrow().location
    }
}
```

Updated `main.rs`:

```rust
use stdweb::traits::*;
use stdweb::unstable::TryInto;
use stdweb::web::document;
use stdweb::web::event::MouseDownEvent;
use stdweb::web::html_element::CanvasElement;
use stdweb::web::CanvasRenderingContext2d;

use game::Game;

mod game;

// https://github.com/koute/stdweb/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/main.rs#L31-L39
macro_rules! enclose {
    ( ($( $x:ident ),*) $y:expr ) => {
        {
            $(let $x = $x.clone();)*
            $y
        }
    };
}

fn game_loop(game: Game, context: CanvasRenderingContext2d, timestamp: f64) {
    game.update(timestamp);
    draw(&game, &context);

    stdweb::web::window().request_animation_frame(|time: f64| {
        game_loop(game, context, time);
    });
}

fn draw(game: &Game, context: &CanvasRenderingContext2d) {
    context.clear_rect(0., 0., 800., 800.);
    context.set_fill_style_color("red");

    let location = game.location();
    context.fill_rect(location.x, location.y, 5., 5.);
}

fn main() {
    let canvas: CanvasElement = document()
        .query_selector("#canvas")
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap()
        .try_into()
        .unwrap();

    canvas.set_width(800);
    canvas.set_height(600);

    let context = canvas.get_context().unwrap();

    let game: Game = Game::default();

    canvas.add_event_listener(enclose!( (game) move |event: MouseDownEvent| {
        game.set_destination(event);
    }));

    game_loop(game, context, 0.);
}
```

---

P.S. Please, before sharing any code in the future, install and use the [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt).

Comment: I see now how much of a hassle keeping the Game as a local variable actually is. Since there always will be only a single Game that should be alive through all lifetime of the application then it makes much more sense to KISS it as a singleton. From what I saw lazy_static and a Mutex is a perfect way of creating a singleton. I actually refactored my code this way and achieved something that smells good to me. Thanks for the rustfmt i will use it. I just really hate Cleopatra parentheses.